# Remove multiple occurrences between characters in string

Tags: c#, .net

```
string Test = "SET @rhsLclGrpVar = CAST(@variable1 AS CHAR(3)) /*RHS: X(03)*/+ 
CAST(@variable2 AS CHAR(42)) /*RHS: X(42)*/+ CAST(@variable3 AS 
CHAR(8)) /*RHS: X(08)*/";
```

I want to remove anything that comes between

```
"/*" and "*/"
```

For single occurence I have a code like :

```
int startIndex = item.IndexOf("/*");
int endIndex = item.LastIndexOf("*/");
string Output = item.Replace(item.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - 
startIndex + 2), string.Empty));
```

This works fine in case of single occurrence.

Comment: There are other choices.. however, for the sake of simplicity, how about.. a while loop, and while it finds an index of /* keep going?

Comment: As suggested by BugFinder, something like: `int startIndex; while ((startIndex = item.IndexOf("/*") != -1)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was looking for something cleaner than while loop. Reason being this code is embedded inside for loop which reads file. It can get messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex for that:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/\*.*?\*/");
string output = rgx.Replace(item,"");
```

When running this in the `csharp` interactive console, we get:

```
csharp> using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
csharp> string item = "SET @rhsLclGrpVar = CAST(@variable1 AS CHAR(3)) /*RHS: X(03)*/+ CAST(@variable2 AS CHAR(42)) /*RHS: X(42)*/+ CAST(@variable3 AS CHAR(8)) /*RHS: X(08)*/"; 
csharp> Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/\*.*?\*/");                                                                                                                                    
csharp> rgx.Replace(item,"");                                                                                                                                                    
"SET @rhsLclGrpVar = CAST(@variable1 AS CHAR(3)) + CAST(@variable2 AS CHAR(42)) + CAST(@variable3 AS CHAR(8)) "
```

The regex works as follows: the `/\*` part simply recognizes the `/*` pattern. Next the `.*?` matches *non-greedy* any sequence of characters, but will cut-off from the moment it matches the next part of the pattern, the `\*/` which is the `*/` fragment. By using `Replace` we replace *all* matches of that pattern with the empty string, thus we remove it.

A solution using `IndexOf` could be:

```
string result = item;
while(true) {
    idx = result.indexof("/*");
    if(idx >= 0) {
        idx2 = result.indexof("*/",idx);
        if(idx2 >= 0) {
            result = result.Substring(0,idx)+result.Substring(idx2+2);
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

But this is quite complex (with some chance of still having some bugs) and will probably be less efficient.

Comment: While it is correct, and I'm upvoting it, I'll hate anyone that try to write that regex near me, and I'm quite good with regexes :-)

Comment: @xanatos: well I'm not a fan myself. It is usually better to look for a MySQL parser and manipulate the syntax tree that comes out of it. Like for instance one uses an XML parser for XML manipulation.

Comment: Probably `@"/\*.*?\*/"` would be a little more readable... But still it seems a bad piece of ASCII art (the `/\ ` and `\*/`)

Comment: Thanks Willem. This works fine. Can you brief about the Regex that you have used.

Comment: Was just wondering, if it can be done without regex. Maybe manipulating with indexof method.

Comment: I wonder C# being such an advance language, relies on regex for string manipulation.

Comment: @SumitRoy: note that C# has no standard library. So everybody is free to use whatever tool to parse/manipulate strings, etc.